# PHP ARRAY sort at third level

Tags: php

Hi I am actually trying to sort an array at third level with different keys.

The below is Sample array input.

```
Array
(
    [19067] => Array
        (
            [Morrisville, PA] => 5.02
        )

    [18977] => Array
        (
            [Washington Crossing, PA] => 6.63
        )

    [08695] => Array
        (
            [Trenton, NJ] => 2.84
        )

    [08690] => Array
        (
            [Trenton, NJ] => 1
        )

    [08666] => Array
        (
            [Trenton, NJ] => 2.84
        )

    [08650] => Array
        (
            [Trenton, NJ] => 0
        )

    [08648] => Array
        (
            [Lawrence Township, NJ] => 2.88
        )

    [08647] => Array
        (
            [Trenton, NJ] => 2.84
        )

    [08646] => Array
        (
            [Trenton, NJ] => 2
        )

)
```

Can any body help me to sort the above array at third level

Expected result should like:

Output:

```
Array
(
    [08650] => Array
        (
            [Trenton, NJ] => 0
        )

    [08690] => Array
        (
            [Trenton, NJ] => 1
        )   

     [08646] => Array
        (
            [Trenton, NJ] => 2
        )

    [08666] => Array
        (
            [Trenton, NJ] => 2.84
        )   

    [08695] => Array
        (
            [Trenton, NJ] => 2.84
        )

    [08647] => Array
        (
            [Trenton, NJ] => 2.84
        )

    [08648] => Array
        (
            [Lawrence Township, NJ] => 2.88
        )

    [19067] => Array
        (
            [Morrisville, PA] => 5.02
        )

    [18977] => Array
        (
            [Washington Crossing, PA] => 6.63
        )   


)
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uasort($array, function (array $a, array $b) {
    return current($a) - current($b);
});
```

Do note the comments: values which differ less than 1.0 will be sorted as the same. You may want to do `(current($a) - current($b)) * 100` or otherwise round the value, depending on what value ranges you expect.

Comment: something tells me that float values don't always work very well for comparison values ... not sure where i've read that though :/ otherwise, +1

Comment: Floats are fine here. What you mean is that `$foo == 1.2345` will not typically work with floats, since their value isn't guaranteed to be precise.

Comment: Found it, it will implicitly cast to integer, so 0.1 and 0.99 compare the same, which might not always be right :)

Comment: Wut? Where will it cast to an integer?

Comment: it's in the manual under `usort()` - `cmp_function` parameter, the notice there

Comment: Hmm, I see. Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. O_o Multiplying the comparison value by, say, 100 may be a good idea then, depending on what values you expect.

Comment: I only found out recently myself actually; solved in much the same way as you've described ^^